# Can't get external library with browserify and debowerify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, package, gulp, browserify

I have a headache on my hands. Here's my current setup:

- bower to get vendor libraries (angular in this case)
- gulp task to run browserify
- debowerify to make the bower libraries compatible with browserify

**App.js (before browserify):**

```
'use strict';

var angular = require("angular");
var Routes = require("./routes");

angular.module('MyAngularApp')
  .config(Routes);
```

**App.js (after browserify/in the bundle.js):**

```
var angular = require("./../ext/angular/angular.js");
var Routes = require("./routes");

angular.module('MyAngularApp')
  .config(Routes);
```

So far so good, right? It seems like debowerify did it's job and replaced the `angular` with the relative path to the `angular.js` from bower.

But when I debug the `bundle.js` in the browser command line, after executing the first two `require` lines (for `angular` and `Routes`), `angular` is an empty obj, but `Routes` is exactly the correct function that I setup in the export.

**Question:** Why isn't `angular` being imported correctly using the `require` function?

I put this into my `package.json` to get the `debowerify` working:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "debowerify"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't support CommonJS at the moment, so `var angular = require("angular")` doesn't work. Instead of it, use just `require('angular')`.

```
'use strict';

require('angular');
var Routes = require("./routes");

angular.module('MyAngularApp')
  .config(Routes);
```

The Angular object will be loaded globally and it'll be able to be accessed by other JS files, too.

Comment: Amazing. I've been trying using the bowerify-shim, the "browser" property and debowerify also (not in the same time) and it didn't work. This did!

Comment: I managed to expose it with `browserify`  with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216887/empty-object-require-angular-browserify/28342253#28342253

Comment: Same here! I spent ages trying to get browserify and debowerify to work with browserify-shim but this simple answer fixed it for me, thanks!